# How to unload a utility module (opposite of jQuery.sap.require)

Tags: sapui5

I have a problem unloading a [custom utility](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/48/2df92c6e8b429c8fc9022179515194/content.htm) module in Fiori Launchpad. I'd like to do that to clean up resources.

Module definition:

```
jQuery.sap.declare("sap.ui.demo.tdg.util.Formatter");    
  sap.ui.demo.tdg.util.Formatter = {
    methodCall: function() {
...
```

Module is loaded in Component init:

```
myComponentPath.Component.prototype.init = function(){    
  jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.demo.tdg.util.Formatter");
  sap.ui.demo.tdg.util.Formatter.methodCall(); <- error happens here when opening 2nd time
```

I tried to set the module to *null* on Component *destroy* but then I get *undefined* on sap.ui.demo.tdg.util.Formatter when opening the application second time in Fiori Launchpad:

```
myComponentPath.Component.prototype.destroy = function(){
  sap.ui.demo.tdg.util.Formatter = null;
```

Or am I just paranoid and should not care about the resources been cleaned up properly. :)

Thanks!

Comment: I guess Fiori wastes so much resources already that it's not worth cleaning up your small impact ;)

Comment: I think you are right. Don't you think that that's even a bigger problem than unloading utils? Especially with those poor mobile devices.

Comment: absolutely. navigating through a number of fiori apps will load a whole lot of js code + large amounts of data. if all that js+data+shadow dom elements is kept and not properly cleaned up it will notably slow down things and blow up memory consumption. I don't have any details on what Fiori is actually doing to prevent this. You could get a glimps by taking some memory heapshots.

Comment: It says in "SAP Fiori Launchpad for Developers - Architecture Overview":

"Ensure that all controls created by your component are destroyed when the component is destroyed.
All controls which are in the control tree (defined in an XML view in a static way or explicitly added to
a parent control in a JavaScript view) of the component are destroyed automatically..."

But yes, debugging and memory heapshots would be the only way to really know.

Comment: @cschuff It's not about waste of ressources - I would surely not use SAPUI5 at all but a classical web app with HTML/CSS/Vanilla JS if I don't want to waste ressources! In our case, it's the problem that a module with the same name prefix is implemented differently in several applications, so it has to be reloaded by force when navigating from one app to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it with:

```
jQuery.sap.unloadResource("some/util/Formatter.js", false, true, true);
```

**EDIT:**
jQuery.sap.require loads an resource and saves it into an internal map called mModules. With unloadResource you can remove an entrie from this map. The parameters behind the path describes how to handle dependencies like global vars.

But you can read the documentation yourself [here](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/jquery.sap.global.js#L2617).

Comment: Can you explain your answer please

Comment: Thanks Manuel. That seems to remove the module from mModules and it is properly loaded again with the next jQuery.sap.require.

Anyhow, when looking at the network tab, the actual .js resource is not reloaded on subsequent calls to jQuery.sap.require.

Also, unloadResource seems to be a @private method so I suppose we shouldn't rely onto it, should we.

Comment: Yes it Is an private experimental method. But there Is currently no other method to remove loaded modules. But you can do a check if this method exists before calling it. Anyway if you find a better way, please let me know. :)